# 500 Internal Server Error in a chrome extension tool

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, flask, google-chrome-extension

Im  trying to create a chrome extension tool for a phishing email detection system. The system works 'Extract' button to gather sender, subject, and email body text, and a 'Scan' button to analyze the extracted email body for phishing indicators. While I can successfully extract information, clicking the 'Scan' button results in a 500 Internal Server Error displayed in the console. Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

backend.py

```
import traceback
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from flask_cors import CORS
import json
import logging
from http import HTTPStatus


app = Flask(__name__)


# Load the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("mail_data.csv")

# replace null value with null string
mail_data = dataset.where((pd.notnull(dataset)), '')

# label spam mail as 0; authentic as 1
mail_data.loc[mail_data['Category'] == 'spam', 'Category',] = 0
mail_data.loc[mail_data['Category'] == 'authentic', 'Category',] = 1

# Assuming your dataset has a 'text' column containing the email content and a 'label' column for phishing or not
X = mail_data['Message']
Y = mail_data['Category']

# Feature Extraction
feature_extraction = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english', lowercase=True)
X_features = feature_extraction.fit_transform(X)

# Convert Y values as integers
Y = Y.astype('int')

# Train the model
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_features, Y)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_phishing():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_content = request.json.get('email_content', '')
        # Feature extraction for the input data

        email_content_feature = feature_extraction.transform([email_content])
        # Make prediction using the trained model
        prediction = model.predict(email_content_feature)[0]

        

        return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
    # If the request method is GET, return a message
    else:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Please use POST method to make predictions.'})
    

   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

popup.js

```
// Variable to store email subject, sender, and message
let emailSubjectSenderMessage = {};

// Function to send a message to content.js to extract email content
function extractEmailContent() {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    if (tabs && tabs.length > 0 && tabs[0].id) {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { action: 'extractEmailContent' }, (response) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          // Handle any errors in sending the message

        } else {
          // Check if the response contains emailContent
          if (response && response.emailContent) {
            // Extracted email content
            const emailContent = response.emailContent;

            // Extracted sender's email address
            const senderEmail = emailContent.senderEmail;

            // Store the email subject, sender, and message in the variable
            emailSubjectSenderMessage = {
              subject: emailContent.subject,
              sender: senderEmail,
              message: emailContent.body
            };

            // Display the extracted content including the sender's email address
            displayEmailContent(emailContent, senderEmail);
          } else {
            displayErrorMessage('No email data found on this page.');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid tab or tab ID not available.');
    }
  });
}


// Function to display the extracted email content
function displayEmailContent(emailContent, senderEmail) {
  const emailContentDiv = document.getElementById('emailContent');
  emailContentDiv.innerHTML = `<strong>Sender:</strong> ${senderEmail}<br><strong>Subject:</strong> ${emailContent.subject}<br><strong>Message:</strong> ${emailContent.body}`;
}

// Function to display an error message
function displayErrorMessage(message) {
  const emailContentDiv = document.getElementById('emailContent');
  emailContentDiv.textContent = message;
}
```

Comment: The error is on your server. The only way the extension would be involved would be passing some parameters to the server code that makes it throw an exception. Look at your server logs.